# Flask-SQLAlchemy - Is it possible to commit an update in my postgresql database while a separate table is seeding?

Tags: python, database, postgresql, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm currently seeding a table (`table_a`) in my postgresql database using a python script that calls `db.session.commit()` every few seconds (this is a large dataset with over 200,000 items and won't be complete for several more hours of API calls).

I'm also attempting to update a value for a different table (`table_b`), inside the same database. I'm doing this through a separate flask server I've created for the sole purpose of manually updating the values in `table_b`.

Calling `db.session.commit()` in my new server returns no errors, but when querying my database through psql, the fields are not being updated.

Is this because I'm currently seeding another part of this database? I want to continue updating `table_b` fields with the knowledge that my commits will go through once my seeding has completed, but I'm not sure if that's the reason, or if something else is prohibiting those fields from being updated. Is this likely the cause of my problem?

Comment: Unfortunately we need more details to be able to answer - are these two separate processes (e. g. `python service_a.py` / `python service_b.py`) or two endpoints in the same process?  What does the code for updating `table_b` look like (you might be swallowing an exception that could explain what's going on, for example)?

Comment: The seed.py and updateserver.py are separate processes running concurrently, but they both import all db info from the same model.py. ` if result == 'yea':
  b.yea_benefits_donors=True
  db.session.commit()` is the format of my commit in both scripts with slightly varying values, where b is the object and yea_benefits_donors is the attribute.

Comment: On a related note, it shouldn't take hours to insert 200,000 items into a DB - more like a few seconds.  Assuming that it's the DB calls that are slow, not some other external API, you should read [this FAQ entry for SQLAlchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/faq/performance.html#i-m-inserting-400-000-rows-with-the-orm-and-it-s-really-slow)

Comment: The length of time is due to the fact that I have to make two separate API calls for each individual object to get the value I need, and I'm calling them from an external API. There are a lot of conditionals in that script to shrink the amount of records I seed (there are actually 1.3 million in the range, but I don't have time to seed that many, so I'm getting ones that fit a very particular set of pre-reqs). The API is incredibly messy with lots of irrelevant delimiters, but none of the ones I need, so the specifications are mostly being made via if statements, etc.

Comment: Are you introspecting existing tables in the DB or are you using your models to create the DB tables?  And if model-first, are the DB tables created in-process or out-of-process? (I still suspect it's the code responsible for persisting changes to `table_b` that's faulty, but it *might* be a DB-level lock - if you want to see that [this wiki page](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring) explains how to see all locks currently held by PG)

Comment: The tables were made about a week ago with nulled fields for those that had to be added later. I can confirm that seed.py is definitely updating its values in the db, but it's difficult to know if my code for the update server is at fault.  Here's an example:   `summ = Bill.query.filter().all()    
b = summ[int(bill)]   
   
 if result == 'yea':    
  b.yea_benefits_donors=True
  db.session.commit()
`

Comment: Nevermind, that doesn't make any sense - it *should* pick up your changes since you're just doing an update not an insert (if you were doing an insert you'd need to add it to the session, but updates should work the way you have them here).

Comment: Can you perhaps give us a minimal reproducible example?